# StaggeredGridLayoutManager bug

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I have such problem. All my images in recycler view transfering to right side.
[image: screenshot]
This is my adapter

```
    adapter = new GalleryAdapter(new ArrayList<>(), galleryImage -> galleryLocationPresenter.openGallery(galleryImage), getContext());
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ListSpacingDecoration(Helpers.dpToPx(15, getContext())));
    staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    staggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my row view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I also tried gap strategy `GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS`. The same thing.

Comment: If you know the size of your images, try setting the height in the OnBindViewHolder method.

Comment: I dont know the size. Im using picasso to show images                 `Picasso.with(context).load(galleryImage.getImagePath()).into(image);`

Comment: Can't you get the size of the image from galleryImage? It will help you a lot if you set the height of the cardview before drawing it.

Comment: Im getting images from internet, `galleryImage.getImagePath()` returns image url

Comment: Five years later, have you figured it out?